# Is it possible to update only some part of an application on mobile platforms?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, mobile, app-store

I am developing a game which is currently available for desktop, mac, Linux. In this game there is a game updater which downloads only the updated parts of the game.

I want to make a similar flow with mobile platforms. I've seen games of sizes more than 1 GB. To update such games or apps just with a minor change in code, user has to download the entire game completely again. This looks crazy to me.

I want to know is there any facility or process by which I can overcome these issues in my game. My game size on desktop is around 1.75 GB. I use lighter resources for mobiles. So it can be around 700 - 900 MB. But still this is making big downloads for a small update.

let me know your suggestions. Your ideas can suit any of the popular mobile OS like iOS, Android or other. I am not specific in that.

**Let me give an example**

When an app or game is launched it first downloads required updates (form my server) before playing. After it finishes with updates it lets user play the game. I mean there can be an updater component in the same app which performs updates and allows game module to run. this is just a possible example

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, I think you can write the frequently changed code in script such as Lua, then you can only download and replace these script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on Android it can be done easily, you have just to organize things a bit differently...unless your game is really really strange and will be 700-900 MB of code only :D

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Only your code is in the APK.
Your resources are not, they are in an expansion file of the maximum size of 2GB.
User download a really small APK, then download the expansion file.

Just a minor change in the code? New APK, still small, no one will care.
A change in external assets? Use the second expansion file to patch the first.

Comment: Thank you friends. Both iOS and Android answers seem correct. I can't accept two answers.

Comment: Then just upvote the two right answers, and for keeping Stack Overflow useful post yourself an answer containing both solution and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS it can be done. You can download assets during the app running in a background thread, and save them on the device.

Code example:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloader = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(downloader, ^(){

          NSString * documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

          NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
          UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

          if ([image rangeOfString:@"png"].location != NSNotFound) {
               [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
          }
});
```

Comment: Thank you friends. Both iOS and Android answers seem correct. I can't accept two answers.

Comment: @KumarChikkanna, up-voting will be enough :)

Comment: requires 15 reputations.